# optional argument for cite command

Tags: cite-package

It is possible to write a command as

```
\cite[Capter 2]{tag}
```

which will display in the text something as "...as stated in [tag, Chapter 2]...". No problems so far. I want to do the same while inserting a description of an environment. To be clearer, it is possible to write

```
\begin{Proposition}[\cite{tag}]
```

with no problems but when I try to write

```
\begin{Proposition}[\cite[Chapter 2]{tag}]
```

i get an error as

```
Argument of \@citex has an extra }
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It's a FAQ: `\begin{proposition}[{\cite[Chapter~2]{tag}}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In such cases you need to include the `\cite` command in an extra set of braces `{...}`.  This is to help the parser.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[{\cite[Chapter 2]{tag}}]
  Text.
\end{theorem}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{tag} A reference.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a duplicate!